# Tabula doesn't work after converting python script to .exe

Tags: python, tabula, tabula-py

I am using tabula and python to write a script for web scraping. I tested it and it worked, and I need to convert the .py file into .exe so that it can be run on my company's computers (my office banned the installation of python). However, when I convert it using auto-py-to-exe, tabula stopped working. It returns the following error message:

```
Command '['java', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF8', '-jar', 'C:\\Users\\Julian\\AppData\\Local\\
Temp\\_MEI179122\\tabula\\tabula-1.0.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar', '--pages', 'all', '--guess', '--format', 
'JSON', 'C:\\Users\\Julian\\Desktop\\MDS search\\download_pdf\\MDSReport_605408211.pdf']' 
returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I tried putting the tabula folder into the same directory as the .exe file. however, it still doesn't work

Comment: A starting point would be to look at your environment variables when the scripting is running as a script and trying to make sure any relevant variables are set to the same when it is running as an executable. Once you figure out which environment variable is affecting this, you can set it from your script before executing the offending code.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?