# Unhandled exception using tabula (read_pdf) in built .exe

Tags: python, exe, tabula

Example code:

```
from tabula import read_pdf

def loadPDF(pdfPath):
    # Read tables from the PDF file
    tables = read_pdf(pdfPath, pages='all', multiple_tables=True)
    #tables = tabula.io.read_pdf(pdfPath, pages='all')

    return tables

tables = loadPDF('C:\\Users\\andyo\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Code Projects\\Example\\ExamplePDF.pdf')
```

When I run this python script in the editor, it executes without error and I can continue working with the extracted dataframes.

After compiling the script into a standalone .exe and running it, this unhandled exception occurs:

> Failed to execute script 'MinimumExample' due to unhandled exception: Command '['java','-Dfile.encoding=UTF8','-jar','C:\Users\andyo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI209242\tabula\tabula-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar','--pages','all','--guess','--format','JSON','C:\Users\andyo\OneDrive\Desktop\Code Projects\Example\ExamplePDF.pdf']' returned non-zero exitstatus 1.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "MinimumExample.py", line 9, in 
> File "MinimumExample.py", line 6, in loadPDF
> File "tabula\io.py", line 425, in read_pdf
> File "tabula\io.py", line 88, in _run
> File "subprocess.py", line 571, in run
> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF8', '-jar', 'C:\Users\andyo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI209242\tabula\tabula-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar', '--pages', 'all', '--guess', '--format', 'JSON', 'C:\Users\andyo\OneDrive\Desktop\Code Projects\Example\ExamplePDF.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The command used to create the .exe:

> PS C:\Users\andyo> python -m PyInstaller --onefile 'C:\Users\andyo\OneDrive\Desktop\Code Projects\Example\MinimumExample.py' --windowed --name "Minimum Example" -i='C:\Users\andyo\OneDrive\Desktop\Code Projects\Example\icon.ico'

Setup:

Using Python 3.12
Reinstalled tabula-py==2.7.0 due to an issue with the later 2.8 version.
Fresh install of java.

Found this relevant question, but could not solve it.
[Tabula doesn't work after converting python script to .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57671551/tabula-doesnt-work-after-converting-python-script-to-exe)